# About vectors in regards to classes

Tags: c++, stl

I am not the best at wording things so I'm going to use an example to ask my question.

If for example, I was making a FPS game in which I used vectors to store bullets (which would be a class of its own) because I did not know how many bullets I would be dealing with at runtime, how would I go about accessing each element of the vector in order to render every bullet to the screen every so many frames per second (pretend I'm using OpenGL as the rendering API if that helps or makes any difference).

I hope this question is clear enough.

Comment: use `std::for_each` or a regular for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vector<Bullet> bullets;
vector<Bullet>::iterator bullet;
for ( bullet = bullets.begin(); bullet != bullets.end(); bullet++ )
    draw_bullet(bullet->x, bullet->y, bullet->z);
```

*(an iterator is basically a pointer to the element being iterated)*

Comment: Perhaps I worded my question poorly, I would know how to go about using iterators to access each element, but let's say x y and z are public integers within the bullet class, how would I access each of these properties individually if they are contained within a vector?

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<Bullet> v;
void usebullet(const Bullet& b)
{
    // use the members of b, such as b.x, b.y 
}
```

A vector can be iterated in many ways:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
    usebullet(v[i]); // or use v[i].x, v[i].y

for (std::vector<Bullet>::const_iterator it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it)
    usebullet(*it); // or use it->x, it->y
```

c++0x:

```
for (auto& bullet: v)
    usebullet(bullet);  // or use bullet.x, bullet.y
```

---

To iterate in reverse:

```
for (size_t i=v.size(); i>0; )
    usebullet(v[--i]);

for (std::vector<Bullet>::const_reverse_iterator it=v.rbegin(); it!=v.rend(); ++it)
    usebullet(*it);
```

Interestingly, *range based for* doesn't do reverse iteration. You can use a number of adaptors (including e.g. `boost::range::adaptors::reversed`)

Comment: decorated with member usage, in case the OP wanted to see more detail :)

Comment: in the reverse case, I think you have an iterator issue, `reverse` iterators are a type of their own.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Of course, I glossed over it (thinking - lightning-style - oh, there is a standard conversion). Of course, that's not enough, thanks, fixing

Answer (score 1):

If `std::vector<Bullet> v;` is your vector, say `v[8]` to get the 9th element. You can iterate `for (std::size_t i = 0, end = v.size(); i != end; ++i)`, but the usual way is to use *iterators*:

```
for (std::vector<Bullet>::iterator it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
  // now "*it" is your element
}
```

Don't erase or insert elements into the vector from within the loop!

Answer (score 0):

```
struct bullet
{
     int x;
     int y;
     int z;
};

std::vector<bullet> bullets;
for(std::vector<bullet>::const_iterator it = bullets.begin(); it != bullets.end(); ++it)
     draw_bullet(it->x, it->y, it->z);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Bullet {
    public:
    Bullet(int ID);
    Draw() {
        // implementation
    }
    // more implementation
};
```

Make a vector:

```
std::vector<Bullet> bullets;
```

Add a new bullet to the vector:

```
bullets.push_back(Bullet(some_unique_ID_var));
```

Iterate through all bullets:

```
for (size_t i = 0, size_t s = bullets.size(); i < s; i++) {
    bullets[i].FollowTarget();
}

// or

for (std::vector<Bullet>::const_iterator it = bullets.begin(); it != bullets.end(); it++) {
     it->Draw();
}
```

or if you compiler supports c++11:

```
for (auto it = bullets.begin(); it != bullets.end(); it++) {
     it->Explode();
}

// or

for (Bullet& b: bullets) {
    b.UpdatePosition();
}
```

And just for completness: :)

```
#include <algorithm>

class ChangeSpeed {
    void operator()(const Bullet& b)
    {
        // do something with b
    }
} speed_change;

std::for_each(bullets.begin(), bullets.end(), speed_change);
```